# How to make grid-template-areas work with grid-area?

Tags: css, grid

I'm getting no effect from the grid-template-areas here:
https://codepen.io/ta3aleb/pen/ErOpvr

```
grid-template-areas: 
    "node1 . . node2 . . . node3"
    "node4 . . . node5 . . node6"
    ". . . . . node7 . .";
```

Any idea what may be causing that ?

Comment: `ul` is in the way. or it should be the grid container itself https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rPQrKo

Comment: @G-Cyr Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`.grid-container` has just one child element which is the `ul` the browser doesn't know how to render just an element into eight columns. Change your selector to

```
.grid-container ul{
...
}
```

Or

```
.grid-container > ul{
...
}
```